# MVC 5 Identity and error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am using the Identity 2.0 and I want to know how to customize the error message when I try to register a user that already been registered.
The follow message is what I receving:

- Name xxxxx is already taken.

Tks.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20452352/issue-with-username-validation-message-in-asp-net-identity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919884/how-to-change-error-message-in-asp-net-identity) and [this blog](http://blachniet.com/2013/11/10/email-addresses-as-user-names-in-asp-net-identity/) helped me.

Applying these directly to your question, you can do it two ways. A quick way that solves this specific problem, and a more involved way that allows you to modify any other Identity errors in the future.

1.) The quick way:
  - Under Controllers/AccountController.cs modify the AddErrors(IdentityResult result) method. Change this:

```
    private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
    {
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
        }
    }
```

To this:
Again, this code is a proposed answer from [Marius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/917868/marius-stanescu) in the question I referenced. I didn't use this myself, but looks like it should work.

```
private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
{
    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
    {
        if (error.StartsWith("Name"))
        {
            var NameToEmail= Regex.Replace(error,"Name","Email");
            ModelState.AddModelError("", NameToEmail);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
        }
    }
}
```

2. A more maintainable and extensible solution is [here on Brian Lachniet's blog](http://blachniet.com/2013/11/10/email-addresses-as-user-names-in-asp-net-identity/). Josh's answer in the same question is the same thing, although Brian's blog explicitly describes how to implement replacing the UserValidator method.

   This is the method I followed, it works. As a bonus he keeps updating it, with the last change making it compatible with Identity 2.0 as of March 28th.

Comment: I had tryed these two tips without success, but, now I try a different way for the second one and works fine. I am just created the new class (CustomUserValidator) and in Register action on AccountController I set the UserManager.UserValidator = new CustomUserValidator<ApplicationUser>(UserManager); before the CreateAsync call.