# Is there a way to override the error messages of [DataType(DataType.Password)]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm using ASP.NET identity with MVC 5. For the password validation I have the following piece of code in the AccountViewModels.cs:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password", ResourceType = typeof(MyResources.LocalizedText))]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

And in the cshtml file:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Unforunately the error messages are built in in the identity system and they are displayed only in English. Since I'm using more than 1 language, I would like to customize the error messages on the result page according to the page current language. Is there any way to accomplish that?

I tried:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyResources.LocalizedText), ErrorMessageResourceName = "password_required")]
[DataType(DataType.Password, ErrorMessage = null, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyResources.LocalizedText), ErrorMessageResourceName = "password_errorDatatype")])]
```

With the above code I was able to override the [Required] error message but NOT the DataType. Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/09/easy-model-and-validation-localization-in-asp-net-mvc3/

Comment: @wal The DataType password validation has a completely different behavior than the Required validation mentioned in your link... Thank you for the link anyway!

Answer (score 2):

To customize the datatype error messages you need to install the localized NuGet packages for AspNet.Identity.Core for each of the languages you want to support.

E.g. for German

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.de
```

Note that the localized packages only exist for a few languages. They don't exist for any Scandinavian languages yet, unfortunately.

If you need other languages than the supported ones you will have to do some kind of hack. Have a look at the following, which includes a suggested workaround from one of the developers on the ASP.NET team: [Asp.Net Identity Localization PublicKeyToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835981/asp-net-identity-localization-publickeytoken)