# MVC 5 translate IdentityResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I rephrase another question I asked earlier.

I have a basic C# Asp.net MVC 5 application. I create an account through the following code (provided by the template in Vs 2013)

```
protected async Task<bool> CreateAccountAndAddRoleAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ApplicationUser user, string password, string role)
{
    var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);

     if (result.Succeeded)
     {
          try
          {
              var roleResult = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, role);
              if (roleResult.Succeeded)
              {
                   //await SignInAsync(userManager, user, isPersistent: false);
                   return true;
              }
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(e);
              throw;
           }
     }
     AddErrors(result);
     return false;
}

protected void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
{
   foreach (var error in result.Errors)
   {
       ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
   }
}
```

The problem is that when the username is already taken (or any other error message), the messages are in English. Such as

> Name xxx is already taken

Instead of

> L'identifiant xxx est déjà utilisé

The problem is that the message is provided by the framework with

> var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);

And the `AddErrors(result);` enumerates the messages (in english) to display them to the user. How can I modify the messages?

I changed the culture in the webconfig file with

```
<globalization uiCulture="fr-FR" culture="fr-FR" />
```

But I still have an English message. In fact, the real problem is that I can't change the message provided by the framework even if I wanted another message in English.

Does anyone know how to change the message provided by the `IdentityResult` ?

Comment: Install the French .NET language pack on the server?

Comment: Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961648/how-to-localize-asp-net-identity-username-and-password-error-messages. Latest comment from the ASP.NET developer was posted just yesterday. Short answer is: these messages are not localizable right now.

Comment: Thanks Andrei! I think I will do it dirty then....

Comment: check this if you need to override error messages in your language. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655578/how-can-customize-asp-net-identity-2-username-already-taken-validation-message

Answer (score 7):

Do not forget to install your language package from nuget
for example:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.ru
```