# Add custom unique property to my IdentityUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am using ASP.NET Core Identity to manage my application users. In order to store some additional properties, I created the class "ApplicationUser", which looks as follows:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public Guid CustomProperty { get; set; }
}
```

What I now want is that `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` gives me an error if the value of `CustomProperty` already exists in the database.

What is the best way to achieve this?

I already found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39125762/4046585. But it seems like a whole lot of work to do for such a simple requirement. Isn't there some kind of attribute that I can decorate the property with in order to accomplish this? Also the mentioned answer is almost 3 years old. So I'm not even sure if it works in ASP.NET Core 2.2

Comment: Are you saying that `CustomProperty` needs to be unique in the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EF core, you could specify that an index should be unique, meaning that no two entities can have the same value(s) for the given property(s).

Add below code in your dbContext `OnModelCreating` and add migrations.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasIndex(b => b.CustomProperty)
        .IsUnique();
```

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want the `CustomProperty` to be sort of unique or something. You can use the `DatabaseGenerated` attribute to achieve that.

Decorate your property like below:

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
     { 
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid CustomProperty { get; set; }

 }
```

You can read more [on that.](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/databasegenerated-attribute)

Comment: Is it really THAT simple...? :)

Comment: I tried this, but I still could insert two entries with the same value of `CustomProperty`. So I'm going with Xing Zous solution now.

Comment: @timnot90 Alright. I must have misinterpreted your question or something. I was thinking the `CustomProperty` is autogenerated. I would have suggested Xing's solution too.