# How to change default error messages of MVC Core ValidationSummary?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Using MVC Core with ASP.NET Identity I would like to change the defaults error messages of ValidationSummary that arrived from Register action.
Any advice will be much appreciated.

[image: ASP.NET Core Register Action]

Comment: You can change this messages from model class

Comment: You should be able to change these Error Messages in the AccountViewModel.cs with the Property `ErrorMessage = "..."` in a DataAnnotation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should override methods of `IdentityErrorDescriber` to change identity error messages.

```
public class YourIdentityErrorDescriber : IdentityErrorDescriber
{
    public override IdentityError PasswordRequiresUpper() 
    { 
       return new IdentityError 
       { 
           Code = nameof(PasswordRequiresUpper),
           Description = "<your error message>"
       }; 
    }
    //... other methods
}
```

In `Startup.cs` set `IdentityErrorDescriber`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...   
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddErrorDescriber<YourIdentityErrorDescriber>();
}
```

The answer is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38199890/5426333