# ASP.NET Core ValidationAttribute message language

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-localization

How can I globally overload error messages getting ,for example, from [Required] attribute? Probably, I should change CultureInfo, but I can't find any tutorials. Language still English as default. Thank you!

Comment: what I know is, you could `[Required(ErrorMessage = @"This is required")]` but that'll be only in one language.

Comment: `ErrorMessage` working good and display any languages, but this is ugly to write same text all the time.

Answer (score 3):

A first reference on globalization and localization of ASP.NET Core is https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/localization.html.

There you'll find information about how to translate data annotations and how to configure ASP.NET Core to select the appropriate language / `CultureInfo` for each request.

> DataAnnotations error messages are localized with `IStringLocalizer<T>`.
>   Using the option ResourcesPath = "Resources", the error messages in
>   RegisterViewModel can be stored in either of the following paths:
>
> Resources/ViewModels.Account.RegisterViewModel.fr.resx
>   Resources/ViewModels/Account/RegisterViewModel.fr.resx

For built-in error messages for identity models (like "This email is already taken.) or basic validation texts you have to do some more configuration. I have documented some work in [ASP.Net Core localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39226053/asp-net-core-localization/39227735#39227735).

Comment: Thank you for answer and link, hope asp.net core team will make it simpler in future, just like in asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `ErrorMessageResourceName` and `ErrorMessageResourceType`,  using resource files to store messages.