# I'm getting C# Razor Page Localization error how do I fix it?

Tags: c#, razor, localization, razor-pages

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
  ***  .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

//------------------------------------------
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRpLIytLtbQ
Hello, I am making a website using c# razor page. I was doing localization by looking at the video below. But where I marked "***" I get the following error. Why do you think it might?

Eror:CS0103 The name 'AddViewLocalization' does not exist in the current context
Same Line :CS1022 Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

The website was considering adding language support. But it was not successful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does not work ASP.NET Core Localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49414086/why-does-not-work-asp-net-core-localization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should be like the following:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
   .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
   .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```

Note that I have removed the semicolon `;` at the end of code line.