# Are there localized resources for dotnet core on Nuget?

Tags: c#, .net-core

`TL;DR` Are there localized resources or satellite assemblies for dotnet Core on Nuget or anywhere else?

I'm looking for ready-made localized resources for aspnet-core model validations and `Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core`, specifically I want do display validation messages (The Email field is required.) and password validation messages (Passwords must be at least 6 characters.) in Polish.

I've already done extensive search and know from multiple answers on StackOverflow ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39227735)) that I can create my own `IdentityErrorDescriber`.

While looking for solutions I've found there exists `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.pl` which contains Polish resources for `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core` in form of a satellite assembliy. I'm unable to find localized packages for `Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core`, even though it also gets messages from resources.

If these resources exists for other languages but not for Polish I'd be glad to help the community and translate it myself.

I find baking custom translations in my source code a bad practice and would love to see some resources reuse here.