# where is password must have at least one lowercase ['a'-'z'] message in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

in registration form when user enter just numeric character it shows "password must have at least one lowercase ['a'-'z']", I need to translate it in my native language, where can I find this message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to localize ASP.NET Identity UserName and Password error messages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961648/how-to-localize-asp-net-identity-username-and-password-error-messages)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, install the identity localized package in Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.tr
```

*(.tr or your localization code .it, .es, .de, .fr etc.)*

Then set culture in web.config:

```
<system.web>
      <globalization culture="tr-TR" uiCulture="tr"/>
</system.web>
```

Now, your identity messages will be automatically set according to your language.

Answer (score 0):

These messages are provided by framework, not from your model, so you cannot use data annotations for this. But you can solve the problem in another way:

**Step 1:** Create resource file for your controller or use shared resource. For example, if your controller is */Controllers/AccountController.cs*, then resource file should be *Controllers.AccountController.de.resx* in your resources folder (depending on configuration; instead of *de* use your locale code).

**Step 2:** Write translations for strings: *PasswordRequiresLower*, *PasswordRequiresNonAlphanumeric*, *PasswordRequiresUpper*. These strings are codes of identity errors. You can see them during debug of registration process after failed registration.

**Step 3:** Do not forget to use *localizer* in your controller

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;

public class AccountController : Controller
{    
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<AccountController> _localizer;

    public AccountController(IStringLocalizer<AccountController> localizer)
    {
        _localizer = localizer;
    }

    // Another code of AccountController class.
}
```

**Step 4**: Add translated descriptions for errors in *registration action*

```
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    // User account created.
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
// User account creation failed.
foreach (var error in result.Errors)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError(error.Code, _localizer[error.Code]);
}
```