# How to find the location of this message for translation in asp.net mvc registration form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created a registration form in User Identity Project . I want to translate this message but I cant find the location of source message . The error message is shown in picture.
Can anyone help me ? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiHrN.jpg)

Here is the Related View Model for password:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH9ZO.jpg)

Comment: Can you show your registration view model code?

Comment: I added the view model to the end of my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should override methods of IdentityErrorDescriber to change identity error messages.

```
public class CustomIdentityErrorDescriber : IdentityErrorDescriber
{
    public override IdentityError PasswordTooShort(int length) { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(PasswordTooShort), Description = $"Passwords must be at least {length} characters."  }; }
    public override IdentityError PasswordRequiresNonAlphanumeric() { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(PasswordRequiresNonAlphanumeric), Description = "Passwords must have at least one non alphanumeric character." }; }
    public override IdentityError PasswordRequiresDigit() { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(PasswordRequiresDigit), Description = "Passwords must have at least one digit ('0'-'9')." }; }
    public override IdentityError PasswordRequiresLower() { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(PasswordRequiresLower), Description = "Passwords must have at least one lowercase ('a'-'z')." }; }
    public override IdentityError PasswordRequiresUpper() { return new IdentityError { Code = nameof(PasswordRequiresUpper), Description = "Passwords must have at least one uppercase ('A'-'Z')." }; }
}
```

and then you need replace default IdentityErrorDescriber in startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...   
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddErrorDescriber<YourIdentityErrorDescriber>();
}
```

The answer is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38199890/5426333

Comment: I guess this solution is related to ASP Net Core , Not Asp net framework

Answer (score 0):

In Asp Net Framework ( The traditional one , not the Core ) there is not a simple way to change or customize Registration Error Messages. Hence , one simple way is changing or translating error messages one by one. First trying to see which error message appear in the screen upon user wrong data , then writing a code in AddError method for changing them. In this way, you have to edit the built-in AddError method. Here is my solution :

```
private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
    {
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            
            if (error.StartsWith("Passwords") && error.Contains("non letter"))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Write your own message");
            }
            
            
            else if (error.StartsWith("Passwords") && error.Contains("one digit"))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "write your own message  ");
            }

             else if("Put More Conditions Here ")
                  { "Put More Declarations Here"}

            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
            }                

    }
```

I tried this way and it works smoothly !