# Resolve custom IdentityErrorDescriber from ASP.NET Core DI

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, razor-pages, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-7.0

I created a custom [`IdentityErrorDescriber`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/610fe433e07b32ed451ed99d07df63be47c29050/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/IdentityErrorDescriber.cs) based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38199890/9971404) approach, and registered it like so:

```cs
services
  .AddIdentityCore<CustomUser>()
  .AddErrorDescriber<CustomIdentityErrorDescriber>()
  // ...
```

I need an instance in a razor page model, which has this constructor:

```cs
public RegisterModel(CustomIdentityErrorDescriber errorDescriber, /* ... */)
{
  // ...
}
```

However I get an exception when requesting that page:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.CustomIdentityErrorDescriber' while attempting to activate 'MyProject.Pages.RegisterModel'.

If I change the ctor to use the default `IdentityErrorDescriber` type, then it works. Interestingly, it is actually an instance of `CustomIdentityErrorDescriber`!

How can I resolve the custom type? Must I register it separately (in which case must I somehow deregister the default implementation from the container)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out... it's a registration issue.

This:

```cs
.AddErrorDescriber<CustomIdentityErrorDescriber>()
```

Works [like so](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b2dd5b427ba5c21cdc5572d0d9bf94598721c2f7/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/IdentityBuilder.cs#L104):

```cs
public IdentityBuilder AddErrorDescriber<T>() where T : IdentityErrorDescriber
{
  Services.AddScoped<IdentityErrorDescriber, T>();
  return this;
}
```

So the solution is:

```cs
services
  // ...
  .AddErrorDescriber<CustomIdentityErrorDescriber>();

services.AddScoped<CustomIdentityErrorDescriber>();
```

Then the same describer object can be resolved as `IdentityErrorDescriber` and `CustomIdentityErrorDescriber`.